# Working with Google Tag Manager from a server

Tags: python, authentication, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager

I have a Python script that gets a list of tags, variables and triggers from the Tag Manger API and loads it into BigQuery.
I want to automate it. I run script in server with CentOS and get request open link for authorization.

```
Your browser has been opened to visit:
    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=396356376607-ur3sia6lcgqppup2bt3p9a23l6lco3so.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Ftagmanager.edit.containers&access_type=offline&response_type=code
If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
application with the command-line parameter
  --noauth_local_webserver
```

If I use secret-json for service account, I get error

```
The client secrets were invalid: 
Invalid file format. See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets Expected a JSON object with a single property for a "web" or "installed" application
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0
To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:
   client_secret.json
with information from the APIs Console <https://code.google.com/apis/console>.
```

What do I need to do so that I don’t need to follow the link for authorization?

Comment: Don't have time for an elaborate answer, but look for "service account" - you can download a json file with credentials, which can be processed by a server side application to to non-interactive authentication.

Comment: Hi, Eike. As I wrote, if I use json for service account, I get an error "Expected a JSON object with a single property for a "web" or "installed" application"